# How to mock property injection dependency using AutoMock

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, autofac, automoq

How to mock a property injection.

```
using (var mock = AutoMock.GetLoose())
{
    // mock.Mock creates the mock for constructor injected property 
    // but not property injection (propertywiredup). 
}
```

I could not find similar here to mock property injection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because [**property injection is not recommended in the majority of cases**](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/register/registration.html#property-injection), the approach will need to be changed to accommodate that case

The following example registers the subject with the `PropertiesAutowired()` modifier to inject properties:

```
using Autofac;
using Autofac.Extras.Moq;
using FluentAssertions;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

[TestClass]
public class AutoMockTests {
    [TestMethod]
    public void Should_AutoMock_PropertyInjection() {
        using (var mock = AutoMock.GetLoose(builder => {
            builder.RegisterType<SystemUnderTest>().PropertiesAutowired();
        })) {
            // Arrange
            var expected = "expected value";
            mock.Mock<IDependency>().Setup(x => x.GetValue()).Returns(expected);
            var sut = mock.Create<SystemUnderTest>();

            sut.Dependency.Should().NotBeNull(); //property should be injected

            // Act
            var actual = sut.DoWork();

            // Assert - assert on the mock
            mock.Mock<IDependency>().Verify(x => x.GetValue());
            Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
        }
    }
}
```

Where definitions used in this example ...

```
public class SystemUnderTest {
    public SystemUnderTest() {
    }

    public IDependency Dependency { get; set; }


    public string DoWork() {
        return this.Dependency.GetValue();
    }
}

public interface IDependency {
    string GetValue();
}
```